# Using montage to combine two pictures into single

Tags: images

I have two images IMG01.png and IMG02.png. I want to make a collage of these two images and get a single image Out.png. I don't want the quality of the images to be diminished.

How can I achieve this with montage in the terminal?

Comment: Horizontally? Vertically?

Comment: Try with `feh`  and use 'montage' as described in `man feh`, or more advanced, install and use `image-magick` or `gimp` for a single task or a few tasks.

Comment: `montage IMG01.png IMG02.png Out.png`. For more options see `man montage`.